# How to convert two excel columns into json with python?

Tags: python, json, excel

I have an excel file something like this:

```
name   gender   fac1(radio)   fac2(tv)   fac3(cycle)   fac4(bike)   hasCard   cardNo
a1     f         y              y           n             y          n         
a2     m         n              n           y             n          y         AHJS5684
```

How can I get a structure like below from the above xls file

```
"name": "a1",
"gender": "f",
"facilities": ["radio", "tv", "bike"],
"card": {
   "exists": "n"
   "cardNo": ""
}
```

I have just read the excel file so far in my code:

```
import pandas as pd
#reading excel
df = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Culture\\Artist_Data\\EZCC\\Madur.xlsx")
new_df = df.assign(facilities = df.filter(like = 'fac').apply(lambda x: x.str.lower().dropna().tolist(), axis=1))
d = df.to_dict('records')
```

The above code does not give desired results at all.

Comment: First, you input fields do not match at all your output fields. Second, there is no field that contains 'fac' so `df.filter(like='fac')` returns empty df.

Comment: it does... I edited each of the columns like `fac1(radio)`, `fac2(tv)` etc in the excel sheet. Sorry i didnt include it here in the question.

Comment: So please refactor your question to match your work and somehow your desired output. We cannot help if essential data is missing.

Comment: there is a `DataFrame.to_json()` function, [see here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html)

Comment: @OhadChaet done

Comment: @reportgunner: `to_json` exports in a special format which is not the one asked by OP.

Comment: that function cannot help to get the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas is great as dataframe processing, not at json formatting. But `apply` can tranform lines (or columns') of a dataframe in anything including a dict, and `list` converts trivially a pandas series into a list.

That means that the required transformation can just be:

```
labels = {'fac1(radio)': 'radio', 'fac2(tv)': 'tv', 'fac3(cycle)': 'cycle', 
          'fac4(bike)': 'bike' }
d = list(df.fillna('').apply(lambda x: {
    "name": x['name'],
     "gender": x['gender'],
     "facilities": [labels[i] for i in labels.keys() if x[i] == 'y'],
     "card": {
         "exists": x['hasCard'],
         "cardNo": x['cardNo']
     }}, axis=1))
```

You can control that

```
print(json.dumps(d, indent=2))
```

gives as expected:

```
[
  {
    "name": "a1",
    "gender": "f",
    "facilities": [
      "radio",
      "tv",
      "bike"
    ],
    "card": {
      "exists": "n",
      "cardNo": ""
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "a2",
    "gender": "m",
    "facilities": [
      "cycle"
    ],
    "card": {
      "exists": "y",
      "cardNo": "AHJS5684"
    }
  }
]
```